# How to access from C++ and through COM interoperability a property of a .NET class

Tags: c#, c++

I have a .NET library written in C# that I need to access from C++. The code of the library is implemented like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IClass2
    {
        int DoSomething2();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class2 : IClass2
    {
        public Class2()
        {
        }

        public int DoSomething2()
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IClass1
    {
        int DoSomething1();
        Class2 class2Obj { get; set; }
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1 : IClass1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
        }

        public int DoSomething1()
        {
            // do something
        }

        private Class2 class2InternalObj;

        public Class2 class2Obj
        {
            get
            {
                return class2InternalObj;
            }
            set
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is accessing through a C++ client the "DoSomething2" method implemented in "Class2" after having obtained the access to the interface to Class1.
The C++ code I'm using, which compiles without problems, is the following:

```cpp
// Create the interface pointer.
IClass1Ptr m_ptrClass1(__uuidof(MyNameSpace::Class1));

int nReturnVal;
m_ptrClass1->DoSomething1 (&nReturnVal);    // this works

_Class2 *class2;
m_ptrClass1->get_Class2Obj(&class2);

IClass2 *ptrClass2;
class2->QueryInterface (__uuidof(MyNameSpace::IClass2), (void**) &ptrClass2);

ptrClass2->DoSomething2 (&nReturnVal);  // this DOESN'T work and generates an exception 0xc00000005
```

the ptrClass2 pointer appears to contain a valid pointer but when its DoSomething2 method is invoked I get an exception: what I'm doing wrong? Is there any alternative method or better practice in this case to access methods of the Class2 class?

Thanks in advance and Kind Regards

Severino

Comment: I don't see any signal, beyond the recommendation to never return objects, only interfaces.  The rough diagnostic is that you are using an old version of the type library, one that doesn't have the changes you made in your C# code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for given suggestions but, after further analysis, it came out that the issue was not related to a wrong usage of COM interoperability but to an error inside the code of the DoSomething2 method.

Answer (score -1):

If I were you I would use C++/CLI to accomplish this. 
Have a look at the following project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/556582/UsingplusC-plusfromplusnativeplusC-b-bpluswith